# What is a "domestic hack"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [domestic-hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestic-hacks) with no definition.

---

Currently the questions that use this tag are:

[How to remove screws with stripped heads?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/194/is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-stripped-screw-from-a-hard-drive)

[How can I eat an apple without getting sticky fingers?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/187/how-can-i-eat-an-apple-without-getting-sticky)

[How to remove mould (fungus) from clothes?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/183/how-to-remove-mould-fungus-from-clothes)

https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-do-i-unscrew-a-rusted-bolt-screw

[How to cover nail holes effectively and inexpensively?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/164/how-to-cover-nail-holes-effectively-and-inexpensively)

[How can I (painlessly) add/remove keys to my key ring?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-can-i-painlessly-add-remove-keys-to-my-key-ring)

[What is the best way to light a hard-to-reach candle wick without burning your finger?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-is-the-best-way-to-light-a-hard-to-reach-candle-wick-without-burning-you-fi)

[How can I stop my shower from dripping](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-stop-my-shower-from-dripping)

[What can I do to find the end of the tape roll easily?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/126/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-end-of-the-tape-roll-easily)

[Quick way to defrost food?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/115/quick-way-to-defrost-food)

[If I break a window, how can I keep out cold air while I buy another?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/114/if-i-break-a-window-how-can-i-keep-out-cold-air-while-i-buy-another)

[What is the best way to cool off with an oscillating fan without having it blowing directly on me?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-the-best-way-to-cool-off-with-an-oscillating-fan-without-having-it-blowi)

---

I'm not really seeing anything in common between these questions. Is this a tag for hacks that haven't been imported from another country? Which country?

Before this tag becomes any messier, could we come up with a definition for what it is, and what types of questions are supposed to use it? Or delete it?

Comment: It looks to me like it describes "problems one might have in one's home".

Comment: Possible synonym of the 'home' tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created this tag for all posts that are related to workarounds and hacks that are useful in a household.

As abby mentioned, it is for posts that provide hacks for "problems one might have in one's home".

Comment: If there are [domestic-hacks], what over tags are there that cover this space? [outside-hacks]? [car-hacks]? I suspect this will become far too broad (and inconsistently applied). Domestic hacks does not really help categorize a question into anything useful; something that a specific group might want follow at the exclusion of all others. It just doesn't seem like a good use case for tags.

Comment: @Robert: Ok, then should we burninate it?

Comment: Probably. I'm having trouble envisioning how this will help better organize the content.

Comment: @Robert: It categorizes hacks related to stuff inside the household. Stuff related to curtains, cupboards, windows, lighting, shower.

Comment: @Sunshine and Robert: I have retagged them all to [tag:home], this to make sure 'xxxxx-hacks' tags will not keep popping up everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, that is a much better tag.